# Try and catch help for java beginner

Tags: java

```
public void addNewUser(String username, String password) throws exceptions.InvalidUsernameException,
            exceptions.InvalidPasswordException,
            exceptions.DuplicateUserException {
        // Check if the username has a correct format`enter code here`
        if (EligibilityCheck.getInstance().checkingUserName(username)) {
            throw new InvalidUsernameException();
            // Check if the password has a correct format
        } else if (EligibilityCheck.getInstance().checkingPassword(password)) {
            throw new InvalidPasswordException();
            // If correct format, a new user is added
        } else {
            // Check if username is already being used
            if (loginVault.containsKey(username)) {
                throw new DuplicateUserException();
            } else { //If not, success
                loginVault.put(username, CaesarCipher.getInstance().encrypt(password));
                userLogin.put(username, null);
            }
        }
    }

private static void testAddUserExceptions() {
    System.out.println("** 2. Testing exceptions for addNewUser: **");
    System.out.println();

    addOneUser("bob", "mypass123!");
    addOneUser("bobismyname", "mypass123");
    addOneUser("sheila", "mypass123!");
}



private static void addOneUser(String username, String password) {
    System.out.printf("Attempting to add user '%s' and password '%s'\nAdded user '%s'",
        username, password, username);

    try {
        vault.addNewUser(username, password);
    } catch (InvalidUsernameException | InvalidPasswordException |
        DuplicateUserException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The program is not supposed to print out the output below, but they are printing out for some reason and I do not know why or how to fix them.

```
addOneUser("bob", "mypass123!");
addOneUser("bobismyname", "mypass123");
addOneUser("sheila", "mypass123!");
```

Each test should fail due to the exception I have created. For instance,

> 'attempting to add user 'bob' and password 'mypass123!'```

> Error: The username is invalid; enter 6-12 lower-case letters.```

Comment: Did you provided exception message ? Could you share `addNewUser`  method?

Comment: Yes, please share your addNewUser method

Comment: Just added the method

Comment: Indeed, you did not provide exception messages :)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to validate within the addNewUser method. And then `throw` an exception when your validate hits.

Example

```java
if(username.length > 10) {
   throw new Exception("Username is too long");
}
```

it will then be catched by your try-catch statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here. With a try-catch block you can manage exceptions that occur in your program flow.

When writing a program it's a good idea to make it as clear as possible so that other people reading it later can understand it better. To that end, consider refactoring the methods. For example

```
public void addNewUser(String username, String password) throws exceptions.InvalidUsernameException,
        exceptions.InvalidPasswordException,
        exceptions.DuplicateUserException {
    // Check if the username has a correct format
    if (EligibilityCheck.getInstance().checkingUserName(username)) {
        throw new InvalidUsernameException();
    }
    // Check if the password has a correct format
    if (EligibilityCheck.getInstance().checkingPassword(password)) {
        throw new InvalidPasswordException();
    }
    // Check if username is already being used
    if (loginVault.containsKey(username)) {
        throw new DuplicateUserException();
    }
    //If not, success
    loginVault.put(username, CaesarCipher.getInstance().encrypt(password));
            userLogin.put(username, null);
}
```

This goes through all the checks in sequence just like the if/else branches did but it's clearer to read.

The `addOneUser` method doesn't do anything (apparently) meaningful when an exception is raised. Consider using the exception handling to send meaningful messages to the user as appropriate.

You mention the program is not printing the output you expect it to. Look into using a testing framework for your test cases, such as junit, so that you can make assertions, look at code coverage, etc. For a simple example in plain English, the first check is on the user name for the correct format. From the code it's not evident what that might be. If for instance a "valid username" is one with only lowercase a-z characters, then you could make the following test cases:

> When a username with anything other than a-z (such as A-Z, 0-9, special characters) is provided, an invalid user exception will be thrown

> WHen a username with only a-z characters is provided, no user exception will be thrown

You can then write these tests and use assertions as appropriate.

Consider also using a static analysis tool like sonar to help with code quality.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix your problem, you should just provide exception messages.

```java
public void addNewUser(String username, String password) throws exceptions.InvalidUsernameException, exceptions.InvalidPasswordException, exceptions.DuplicateUserException {

        // Check if the username has a correct format`enter code here`
        if (EligibilityCheck.getInstance().checkingUserName(username)) {
            
            // HERE 
            throw new InvalidUsernameException("Error: The username is invalid; enter 6-12 lower-case letters.");

        } 
        ...
        ...
    }
```